# Атомарность Multithreading

Tags: java

```
synchronized void takeBackSalary(int salary){
        this.salary = bank.deal(salary);
 }
```

Данный метод нужно синхронизировать, как я сделал, или процесс и без этого атомарный?

*Использованный внутри метод синхонизирован.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атомарность присваивания зависит от типа переменной `salary`.

Тем не менее, это не единственный аспект, на который нужно обратить внимание. Если значение переменной `salary` читается из несколькоих потоков, то необходимо обеспечить видимость изменения этой переменой другим потокам. Ваш пример ее обеспечивает из-за `synchronized`. Хотя аналогичного эффекта можно достичь с помощью модификатора `volatile` или атомарных ссылок (`AtomicRef` или другой класс, в зависиомсти от типа).

PS: Прочитайте уже книгу "Concurrency in practice" и многое встанет на свои места. Не дело это, изучать тонкости многопоточного программирования с помощью форумов.

Comment: если б это одну книгу по Multithreading осталось пройти, а еще огого сколько технологий, Hibernate, Java Persistence API, EJB, Apache... Сколько же времени надо, чтоб по всем книги прочитать

Comment: @romashechka Сколько же времени надо, чтобы все это на форумах обсудить :)

Comment: все равно вам в репутацию )))